# try to multiply a value for a matrix in order to get another new matrix, error in "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I made a loop `for(x in 1:nrow(std)){ std3[x,] <- std[x,]*wt }`

I have variable wt (in a dataframe): (nrow = 1, ncol = 20) `wt
        MAT        MWMT        MCMT          TD         MAP         MSP 
0.017671149 0.014570650 0.017590221 0.013502170 0.012492879 0.012123104 
        AHM         SHM        DD_0         DD5        NFFD        bFFP 
0.012687610 0.015350388 0.020480264 0.018187111 0.016277024 0.012101312 
       eFFP         FFP         PAS         EMT         EXT        Eref 
0.011703445 0.013804658 0.010790885 0.016859298 0.014416079 0.015454274 
        CMD         MAR          RH 
0.015151816 0.005430275 0.007500012`

I have a matrix generated after apply function named std:  but the structure of std seems strange to me, it is like a named numerical list of 2. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdUAw.png)

I made a new matrix named std3:`std3 <- matrix(ncol = 20,nrow = nrow(std));str(std3)`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alxlw.png)

Problem here is: `Error in std3[x, ] <- std[x, ] * wt : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

I think it's the std matrix problem but don't know how to fix it, please help. Thanks!

Comment: I think you need `unlist(wt)`  and this could be done without a loop as well `std * unlist(wt)[row(std)]`

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) and show expected output based on that.

Comment: Both `std` and `std3` have 20 columns, but `wt` has 21 columns according to your printout. Once you get that straightened out, I think `std3 <- sweep(std, 2, wt, "*")` will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks everyone, its working now!